# Bad OOP to have lots of classes with only 1 or 2 methods

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Is it a sign of bad design where you have lots of classes with only 1 or 2 methods in them?

I am trying to learn OOP design and have created a small application (tiny).

It has ended up with quite a few classes implementing interfaces that contain only 1 or 2 methods.

It feels nicely seperated but it seems bad that the classes have so few methods.

I know each scenario will be different but is this bad from a general point of view?

A small part of the application determines schedules for feeding dogs (lame i know):

So i have tried to implement the strategy pattern here:

```
class DogFeedController
{
    protected $strategy = null;

    public function __construct(iDogFeedStrategy $strategy) {
        $this->strategy = $strategy;
    }

    public function getFeedingSchedule() {
        $morningFeeds = $this->strategy->generateMorningFeeds();
        $eveningFeeds = $this->strategy->generateEveningFeeds();       
    }

}


class GeneralFeedStrategy implements iDogFeedStrategy
{
    public function generateMorningFeeds() {
        //do stuff here
    }

    public function generateEveningFeeds() {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: It really depends. It would be very nice to see some concrete examples.

Comment: i have update with a small example from the application which highlights what i am talking about.

Comment: @user1189880 it does **not** highlight a thing :). Having classes with one or two public functions is a good thing. But they can't be to long (because they will become hard to understand), so whenever possible and needed - extract some releated logic to private functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to measure for yourself if it's too much. OOP is a great way to separate logic in a meaningful and real-world way, but it can also reach a point where it negatively affects maintainability, and at that point it is being applied incorrectly.

Think about where the application is going. Is it always going to be a small app? If so, you don't need to create a lot of very generic interfaces. Try to combine them, and if only one class is implementing the interface, you might be able to remove the interface entirely.

If you anticipate your application will grow substancially, the interfaces might actually help you maintain and add features in the future. For example if you created an application to manage a car lot that only has parking spaces for cars, you might want to create a generic automobile interface if you anticipate growth to different types of vehicles (e.g. motorcycles only take half a parking space). That said, you shouldn't try to cover every conceivable change in requirements at the onset of a project and make the code too abstract. Measuring the risk of change in requirements can help you predict what code needs to be abstracted.

If you're a software engineer on a team, diagram your design and show it to your colleagues to get their opinions too.

Finally, be careful of [code smells](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html).

Answer (score 7):

From a general point of view both having classes that are too large or on the contrary are too small are considered to be a bad practice and referred to as the so called **Code Smells**. The two I am referring to are the **Large Class** (aka *God Object*) and **Lazy Class** (aka *Freeloader*).

Here are the definitions from the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and the [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html):

> Large class: a class that has grown too large.
>
> Large classes, like long methods, are difficult to read, understand, and troubleshoot. Does the class contain too many responsibilities? Can the large class be restructured or broken into smaller classes?

and

> Lazy class: a class that does too little.
>
> Classes should pull their weight. Every additional class increases the complexity of a project. If you have a class that isn't doing enough to pay for itself, can it be collapsed or combined into another class?

On the other hand, there is a Principle for the Object-Oriented Design called the **Interface Segregation Principle** which states that "Clients should not be forced to depend on methods that they do not use". In Your case, the interfaces with fewer methods actually do conform to this Principle.

To summarize the above, Your design is pretty much correct. Interfaces with fewer methods are good so that the classes that implement those interfaces don't have to implement all the methods along with the ones they don't use. As to the classes, I believe that eventually they will grow larger. Just remember that implementing an interface doesn't mean that You can't have more methods than are defined in the implemented interface. That is, try to put more logic there.

More on the **SOLID**, the Object-Oriented Design Principles, can be found on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

PS. The Code Smells are the symptoms of bad design, and the SOLID is the treatment.

Comment: The Coding Horror link is broken, here's a mirror: https://web.archive.org/web/20120313053627/http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the question you should ask yourself is. Is this class responsible of what it is doing? Being able to identify and separate responsabilities is a cornerstone in OOP. You could have a `Security` class with only one method that creates a random password, for instance.

I think (and this is my opinion) that if the random password is only used in the register, instead of creating a private method of that class, I would separate that method into a new class, `Security`, because I don't think that is a responsability of the `Register` class.

Moreover, since your application is a small one, it could be perfectly normal to have few methods per class.

---

**Edit:** Seeing your code I could make some advices, but bear in mind that I can not see the entire picture.

If you have not, you should read about [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you might not have views in your application, but separating controllers from models is a good practice.

Your `DogFeedController` seems to be a controller, and `GeneralFeedStrategy` the model. I like to end the name of my classes with what they are. For example, `UserController`, `UserView` and `UserModel`. I think that this makes things clear, but again, this is my opinion.

I do not see the point of having `iDogFeedStrategy` but again, I am not seen the entire picutre. The basic usages of an interface are to ensure that a group of classes, no matter how different they are, will have the same *API* and to encapsulate the details of each class implementing the interface.

Comment: The controller is not a controller in the sense of mvc.  Maybe bad wording on part, perhaps manager or generator would be a better word to describe it. iDogFeedStrategy is part of the strategy pattern i was trying to imimplement and GeneralFeedStrategy being the a concrete example

Comment: @user1189880 Ah ok, I see it know, then this part that you are showing seems well programmed. Although it is still hard to evaluate it without all the code....

Answer (score 0):

Another important aspect of OOP besides separation of concerns is class cohesion.  The class should be "pulling its own weight" rather than having many other things call its "getters" and do something with the information.  Create interfaces if you want polymorphic behavior, or if you plan on extending your app in the future.  Don't create interfaces just for the sake of separation.  if the interfaces are not being implemented by two or more subclasses, get rid of them.  (you can also use interfaces to apply the dependency inversion principle, to break dependency cycles)

Design decisions in OOP should always be made to consciously address a specific problem. Otherwise, keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer lots of small objects with complex relations over few big objects with simple relations as this favors maintainability and it is more prepared for change in the future.

Your design looks very good to me, even more considering you are starting to program now and beginners always do the other way around.